# Return an ObservableCollection depending on enum value

Tags: c#, interface, observablecollection, generic-collections

My C# application defines the following enumeration:

```
public enum ItemTypes {
  REQUIREMENTS,
  TEST_CASES
}
```

Now I would like to define an interface which gets all items matching one of the `ItemTypes` and returns them as an `ObservableCollection`. As I don't know what enum value is passed I thought using a generic `T` would be the way to go. However the following does not work as `T` is not recognized:

```
interface IDataSourceService {
  ObservableCollection<T> GetItems(Enums.ItemTypes itemType);
}
```

The implementing class shall look something like this (more or less pseudo-code):

```
ObservableCollection<T> GetItems(Enums.ItemTypes itemType) {
  // Define an ObservableCollection which could hold "anything".
  ObservableCollection<T> result = null;
  switch (itemType) {
    case Enums.ItemTypes.REQUIREMENTS:
      // Get all requirements from the data source
      ObservableCollection<CRequirement> result = new ObservableCollection<CRequirement>();
      result = foo();
      break;

    case Enums.ItemTypes.TEST_CASES:
      // Get all test cases from the data source
      ObservableCollection<CTestCase> result = new ObservableCollection<CTestCase>();
      result = bar();
      break;
  }      
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `T` would be recognized if `IDataSourceService` was `IDataSourceService<T>`. But then you would have to specify that type when you use the interface as well.

Answer (score 3):

How do you plan to use the result of your function?

If you want to use it through a common interface that `CRequirement` and `CTestCase` share, then you need to separate this common interface e.g. `IMyCommonInterface` and make both of your classes implement it.

Then you can use `ObservableCollection<IMyCommonInterface>`.

If on other hand you will have to test the result of the function and fork the code based on what are the type, then you can simply define your function to return an pure `object`, which you will later test for the correct type anyways.

Comment: The result of the function shall serve as a view model property which will be bound to some WPF control. I think I will go with the second part, i.e. returning an `object`.

Comment: As Petar suggests, return an `ObservableCollection<object>`. You should also understand why your code did not work: In order to use generic typing, the type must be known at compile-time. Your code can only deduce the return type at runtime, in the switch statement.